# Sorting n numbers: precisely how many queries are needed?

Tags: sorting, combinatorics

Suppose I have `n` integers. With each query, I can pick two and compare them. Precisely how many queries do I need to sort them from smallest to largest?

Of course the answer will be of the order `O(n log n)`. But I want an exact answer.

Let `a(n)` be the number queries needed. Then it's clear that `a(n) >= log_2(n!)` (or rather, the smallest integer bigger than that). Does equality occur? This seems to be true for `n<=5`, but I'm not sure in general.

Edit: One sorting algorithm I came up with which comes close is the following. It's clear that if you know the order of `a_1, ..., a_i` and if you want to find out where `a_{i+1}` fits in, you need `log_2(i+1)` queries. Then you can first sort `a_1, a_2`, then add `a_3` (which will take `log_2(3)` queries), then add `a_4` (which will take `log_2(4)` queries), ..., then add `a_n` (which will take `log_2(n)` queries). In total this takes `<= log_2(n!)+n` queries. Incidentally, does anyone know the name of this sorting algorithm?

Comment: What kind of sort are you using? As an example, look at slide 50 of this link: http://pkqs.net/~tre/talks/2013_icalp_quicksort.pdf which outlines the total number of swaps and comparisons needed by various quicksort algorithms. I am by no means an expert in theoretical computer science but the authors of those set of slides are and it seems they even they can't come up with an exact answer. Maybe I'm overthinking this.

Comment: I'm not interested in averages, I'm interested in the worst-case scenario. See the above for one sorting algorithm which comes close to the lower bound I described.

Comment: It seems that your edit is an insertion sort which uses a binary search to find the correct location for a_(i+1).

Comment: Ah okay. Apparently it's known as 'binary insertion sort'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a well established theoretical result for lower bounds on comparison based sorting, and it's `Omega(n lg n)`. It's pretty straightforward to prove using decision trees. Here's a link with some explanation, though you can find much more theoretical work on google by simply searching 'lower bounds on sorting':

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Lower_bound_for_the_average_number_of_comparisons

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't asking for an asymptotic answer; like I mentioned in the question, I'm aware of the `Omega(n lg n)` bound. The link has a discussion of this question (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list). Apparently the answer is not known, and the lower bound log_2(n!) is not sharp for n=13.